# How to join with equal sign and add single quote to the integer in Jinja2

Tags: jinja2

I have string variable k = 'level' and an integer variable v = 4.

Is there an easy way to output `level='4'` in jinja1/2 ?

I tried with `Join`. Obviously, it won't work and I wish to add the single quote to the integer.

```
{{ [k, v]|join('=') }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
{{ k }}='{{ v }}'
```